# Android: Can I force app input from phone mic with bluetooth connected?

Tags: microphone, bluetooth-audio

My car a Nissan Leaf does cell and ad2p bluetooth connect. The car mic works fine for cell calls, and ad2p works fine for audio output of apps.
However, neither the car mic or the phone mic takes app mic input when bluetooth is connected.

This makes the google assistant and any other audio input oriented app useless including a VOIP app for my home phone. Hands free via voice commands (other than cell) is lost.

Is there some way to force the phone to use the phone mic for apps?